# How can I print the entire contents of Wordnet (preferably with NLTK)?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, wordnet, corpus

NLTK provides functions for printing all the words in the Brown (or Gutenberg) corpus. But the equivalent function does not seem to work on Wordnet.

Is there a way to do this through NLTK? If there is not, how might one do it?

This works:

```
from nltk.corpus import brown as b
print b.words()
```

This causes an AttributeError:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
print wn.words()
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For wordnet, it's a word sense resources so elements in the resource are indexed by senses (aka `synsets`).

To iterate through `synsets`:

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> for ss in wn.all_synsets():
...     print ss
...     print ss.definition()
...     break
... 
Synset('able.a.01')
(usually followed by `to') having the necessary means or skill or know-how or authority to do something
```

For each synset (sense/concept), there is a list of words attached to it, called `lemmas`: lemmas are the canonical ("root") form of the words we use to when we check a dictionary.

To get a full list of lemmas in wordnet using a one-liner:

```
>>> lemmas_in_wordnet = set(chain(*[ss.lemma_names() for ss in wn.all_synsets()]))
```

Interestingly, `wn.words()` will also return all the `lemma_names`:

```
>>> lemmas_in_words  = set(i for i in wn.words())
>>> len(lemmas_in_wordnet)
148730
>>> len(lemmas_in_words)
147306
```

But strangely there're some discrepancies as to the total number of words collected using `wn.words()`.

**"Printing the full content"** of wordnet into text seems to be something too ambitious, because `wordnet` is structured sort of like a hierarchical graph, with synsets interconnected to each other and each synset has its own properties/attributes. That's why the wordnet files are not kept simply as a single textfile.

To see what a synset contains:

```
>>> first_synset = next(wn.all_synsets())
>>> dir(first_synset)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__unicode__', '__weakref__', '_all_hypernyms', '_definition', '_examples', '_frame_ids', '_hypernyms', '_instance_hypernyms', '_iter_hypernym_lists', '_lemma_names', '_lemma_pointers', '_lemmas', '_lexname', '_max_depth', '_min_depth', '_name', '_needs_root', '_offset', '_pointers', '_pos', '_related', '_shortest_hypernym_paths', '_wordnet_corpus_reader', 'also_sees', 'attributes', 'causes', 'closure', 'common_hypernyms', 'definition', 'entailments', 'examples', 'frame_ids', 'hypernym_distances', 'hypernym_paths', 'hypernyms', 'hyponyms', 'instance_hypernyms', 'instance_hyponyms', 'jcn_similarity', 'lch_similarity', 'lemma_names', 'lemmas', 'lexname', 'lin_similarity', 'lowest_common_hypernyms', 'max_depth', 'member_holonyms', 'member_meronyms', 'min_depth', 'name', 'offset', 'part_holonyms', 'part_meronyms', 'path_similarity', 'pos', 'region_domains', 'res_similarity', 'root_hypernyms', 'shortest_path_distance', 'similar_tos', 'substance_holonyms', 'substance_meronyms', 'topic_domains', 'tree', 'unicode_repr', 'usage_domains', 'verb_groups', 'wup_similarity']
```

Going through this `howto` would be helpful in knowing how to access the information you need in wordnet: http://www.nltk.org/howto/wordnet.html

Comment: I am using NLTK 3.0.3 and `lemmas_in_words  = set(i for i in wn.words())` gives me: AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'words'

Comment: Upgrade it to NLTK 3.1 `pip install -U nltk` =)

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick. BTW, I see you were at NTU. I visited TW this year for several months and liked it very much.

Comment: I'm glad that the answer helps. BTW, "NTU" is ambiguous, `wn.synsets('NTU') = [ Synset('Nanyang_Technological_University.n.1'), Synset('National_Taiwan_University.n.1') ]`

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

```
for word in wn.words():
    print word
```

This should work because `wn.words()` is actually an iterator that generates a sequence of strings, rather than a list of strings like `b.words`.  The `for` loop causes the iterator to generate the words one at a time.

Comment: I have: AttributeError: 'WordNetCorpusReader' object has no attribute 'words'

Comment: Hmmm...try the following two lines of code and see if you get the same responses as I do: wn.words
Out[10]: <bound method WordNetCorpusReader.words of <WordNetCorpusReader in u'/Users/sbarkin/nltk_data/corpora/wordnet'>>

     wn.words()
Out[11]:    <dictionary-keyiterator at 0x1128cae68>

Comment: No, sorry. Which NLTK are you using? I'm on 3.0.4

Answer (score 2):

This will generate an output of synonyms of all words in synset:

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
synonyms=[]
for word in wn.words():
    print (word,end=":")
    for syn in wn.synsets(word):
      for l in syn.lemmas():
        synonyms.append(l.name())
    print(set(synonyms),end="\n")
    synonyms.clear()
```

Comment: a little explanation would be nice !

Comment: This will generate an output of synonyms of all words in synset

Comment: Please edit your question with the details.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".